# AWS EKS: Error loading GenericResourceCollection/namespaces

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

As you can see from my screenshot, I'm getting a strange error from my cluster.  I tried deleting and recreating it to no avail.

As well as the error message, there are no namespaces listed in the UI.

[image: screenshot],

I definitely do have namespaces, as shown:

```
$ kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   44h
kube-node-lease   Active   44h
kube-public       Active   44h
kube-system       Active   44h
```

Why am I seeing this error and why are my namespaces not showing ?

Comment: How did you defined the security and authentication in the cluster creation? Seems it is an error related permissions with your IAM user.

Comment: For sure IAM issue; have a look here: https://marcincuber.medium.com/amazon-eks-rbac-and-iam-access-f124f1164de7

Comment: If you are not the IAM user/role that created the cluster, and you have not added the current IAM user/role that you are using now to the aws-auth configmap, you will face this issue